# React Quill link sanitization not working in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, quill, react-quill

I am using the react-quill editor in the next.js app. I am facing issues with adding hyperlinks to text. If I add hyperlinks for ex. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) redirects me to http://localhost:3000/app_name/www.google.com. If I add the hyperlink https://www.google.com it works fine. But the user won't always add HTTP or HTTPS while adding hyperlinks to text. After searching on the internet I found that this issue is related to link sanitization so I added the following code in my next.js app.

```
import Quill from 'quill'
try {
  const Link = Quill.import('formats/link');
  Link.sanitize = function (url) {
    // quill by default creates relative links if scheme is missing.
    if (!url.startsWith('http://') && !url.startsWith('https://')) {
      return `http://${url}`
    }
    return url;
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

But the above code is not working well. It works sometimes but also It gives me **Server Error ReferenceError: document is not defined** error on page refresh.

I have also tried to import Quill as mentioned in the following code:

```
const { Quill } = dynamic(import("quill"), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <p>Loading ...</p>,
});
```

But I am getting **TypeError: Quill is undefined**

Comment: Hey did you manage to solve this issue? I am having the same issue exactly and have tried a number of things with no success.

Comment: No, I am not able to solve this issue.